# Very Battery Friendly App/Widget(Android)

Tags: android, android-widget, power-management

I have been looking around here and [There](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html), and I have become curious.

I was wondering if there is anything staple that is usually applied to android apps to make sure they do not become battery hungry. Such as portion of code that is normally added to make sure app gets closed all the way when it is exited?

What would be the best practice(code wise) that I could do to make sure my app/widget does not drain battery life.

For example lets just say my app is an informative one with a little bit of user interaction or a simple widget(Not a game etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best practice is kindof a dead giveaway: "don't make silly mistakes". Ofcourse, that is harden then it seems.

- Closing all the way is not something you need to think of. You should keep as little as possible memory occupied. NOT because that uses battery, but the less you use, the more programs can stay in memory (so the less gets closed!) and can be started without too much trouble. Reloading stuff is expensive, keeping it in memory isn't!
- Be aware that a service (background process, alarm, etc) is costly, because it can actually DO something when it is not in view. Do make sure those are closed.
- Background stuff that should be there (updates, loading etc) should use as little as possible resources, just as normal usage
- normal usage: Use little resources like network, location etc etc. It kinda works like you think. Also, the less memory you use, the more other programs can stay in memory and lower battery life.

Answer (score 1):

If you investigate about battery consumption you will find most of the charged is consumed by wifi,bluetooth,GPS enabled,system and display.So when developing application it should be checked by user how he is using the resource.Also calling finish() while exiting the application free some resources(memory)

Comment: Calling `finish()` to exit your app will, in the long run, end up consuming more battery power than allowing Android to manage the app. This is because the next time you start the app, it has to be reloaded fresh into memory, and any app-specific initialisation needs to take place again instead of just being reactivated.

Comment: @RivieraKid you are working under the hypothesis that the app is going to be reloaded. This may not be true for EVERY app you develop. In case the app isn't used frequently, having it loaded on RAM only means that the most freq. used apps may be swapped for it.

Comment: @Mister - while that particular edge case seems to make an argument in favour of "exiting" your app, the fact is the Android memory manager already maintains an LRU list of apps and will prefer to keep in memory those apps that you use most often. I'd go so far to say that if you're writing an app that's intended to be used rarely (or any app, really, even if I use it every day), but when you do use it, manages resources so badly that you need to second-guess the OS and try to release resources manually, then that's not an app I'd want to put my name to.